# ¿como poner audio a un programa en java?

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo el siguiente codigo para poner audio a una aplicacion que estoy desarrollando , el problema es que me manda el siguiente error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory     at
>   javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayer.(Unknown Source)   at
>   musica.musica2.(musica2.java:12)    at
>   musica.musica2.main(musica2.java:39) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 3 more

no se que estoy haciendo mal, alguna idea?

```
package musica;

import java.io.File;

import javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayer;

public class musica2
{
  private BasicPlayer player;

     public musica2()
     {
      player=new BasicPlayer(); 
     }

    public void Play() throws Exception 
    {
     player.play();
    }

    public void AbrirFichero(String ruta) throws Exception {
      player.open(new File(ruta));
    }

    public void Pausa() throws Exception {
      player.pause();
    }

    public void Continuar() throws Exception {
      player.resume();
    }

    public void Stop() throws Exception {
      player.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    try {
          musica2 mi_reproductor = new musica2();
          mi_reproductor.AbrirFichero("c:/mi_archivo_de_musica.mp3");
          mi_reproductor.Play();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que se estan faltando incluir librerías. Hice una prueba para hacer funcionar el reproductor y requiere las siguientes:

1. basicplayer3.0.jar
2. commons-loggin-api-1.1.jar (debido a que falta esta te esta apareciendo la excepción que mostras)
3. jl1.0.jar
4. msp3spi1.9.2.jar
5. tritonus_share.jar

A continuación una captura con el reproductor arriba y estan marcadas las librerías que son necesarias vincular al proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el link con la documentación, se mencionan algunas otras librerías (sección Required libraries) pero las que indico mas arriba son las necesarias para que tu ejemplo funcione. Yo probé mi ejemplo con un archivo .mp3 y anduvo OK.

http://www.javazoom.net/jlgui/developerguide.html

Un comentario .. por un tema de convención se recomienda que los nombres de clases empiecen con mayúsculas, en mi ejemplo la clase se llama Musica2 y por ende tambien el constructor.

Saludos y espero sea de tu utilidad.